# newValue in scope.$watch is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive that will check the uniqueness of the value entered in to the text box. But newVal and oldVal are always undefined as soon scope.$watch is wrapped in to the ctrl.$parsers.push() function.

Does anybody know why newVal and oldVal are undefined?

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/charms/v6ttW/7/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
{{testVar}}
    <form novalidate>
        <input type="text" name="user.email" ng-model="user.email" email-used="/api/user"/>  
    </form>
</div>
```

**Angularjs**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {email: 'abc', name: 'myname'};
  $scope.testVar = "Test";
}])
.directive('emailUsed', [function() {
       return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                console.log("executing");
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function() {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('eaCheckingUniqueValue', true);
                    if(ctrl.$valid) {
                        console.log("valid");
                        scope.oldValues = [];
                        scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                            scope.oldValues.push(newVal);
                            console.log("new value is: " + newVal);
                        });
                        console.log("valid is true");
                    } else {
                        console.log("valid is false");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You shouldn't be putting a `scope.$watch()` function inside of a parser, as it will register a new `scope.$watch()` every time the parser is executed (which is every time the input changes).

Comment: Thanks for your input rtcherry. That helps much already. Do you have any recommendation how I would get the value of ngModel in to my directive everytime the value changes so that I can verify if it already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you keep getting values that are undefined is because you are not returning a defined value from your parser function.

From the angular documentation for $parsers:

> Array of functions to execute, as a pipeline, whenever the control
>   reads value from the DOM. Each function is called, in turn, passing
>   the value through to the next. Used to sanitize / convert the value as
>   well as validation. For validation, the parsers should update the
>   validity state using $setValidity(), and return undefined for invalid
>   values.

Because you had no return statement in your parser, you were always returning undefined (an invalid value).

Here is [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckRvj7) of what I think you were looking to implement.

Here is the code for the directive:

```
.directive('emailUsed', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            scope.oldValues = [];
            scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (angular.isDefined(newVal)) {
                    scope.oldValues.push(newVal);
                }
            });
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function () {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity('eaCheckingUniqueValue', true);
                    return ctrl.$viewValue;
                }
                ctrl.$setValidity('eaCheckingUniqueValue', false);
                return undefined; // Model is not valid so return undefined.
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Note that like the answer below, the new value is passed into the parser function, so we don't really have to use ctrl.$viewValue.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "how I would get the value of ngModel in to my directive everytime the value changes?", each parser function receives the new value as an argument:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
   console.log("executing");
   scope.oldValues = [];
   ctrl.$parsers.push(function(newVal) {
      ctrl.$setValidity('eaCheckingUniqueValue', true);
      if(ctrl.$valid) {
         console.log("valid");
         scope.oldValues.push(newVal);
         console.log("new value is: " + newVal);
      } else {
         console.log("valid is false");
      }
      ... // see mortalapeman's answer for a complete parser implementation
   });
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/eUu7x/)</kbd>

Comment: Well that makes getting the new value a little nicer, but you have also forgot to return from your parser function. This causes the actual model value to be undefined and always stay that way.

Comment: Thanks @mortalapeman, I was lazy and I was only addressing Christopher's question in the comment on the question: "how I would get the value of ngModel in to my directive everytime the value changes".  Thanks for the complete answer (+1).